# Object reference not set to an instance of an object- Delegates

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, user-controls, delegates

I want to pass value from user control to the aspx page. I am trying to use events and delegates for that. But, I get object reference not set to an instance error.

So, when from the usercontrol, I click on image, the value should be passed

```
Mainpage.aspx


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShoudldCome();
    }

    void MyParentMethod(string id)
    {
        // DO work
    }
    protected void ShoudldCome()
    {
        userControlPage g = new userControlPage();
        g.eventName += new userControlPage.abcDel(MyParentMethod);
    }


userControlPage.ascx

 public delegate void abcDel(string id);
    public event abcDel eventName;
    protected void CallHere()
    {
        eventName(Id); // I GET Id=7 here.
        //ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    }

    protected void OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        var id = e.CommandArgument;
        Id = id.ToString();
        CallHere();
    }
```

Comment: what method does `eventName` hold?

Comment: [This isn't how this works.  This isn't how any of this works.](http://i.imgur.com/wTrEucK.png) event handlers in classic asp.net (lol) are a fignment of the viewstate.  A page creates html, it's set to the user, a button posts back, what happens is deconstructed, then the button's event handler is called.  You can't just add events to a usercontrol and expect them to work anywhere near like an event in a desktop application or even events in asp.net.  So nobody has subscribed to your event, and so you get a NRE when attempting to invoke it.

Comment: @Will Actually, I  want to pass data from a user control to other user control (or 1 user control to the main aspx page and then from main aspx page to 2nd user control), so i read an article here : [link] (http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/03/calling-method-of-parent-page-from-user.html)

Answer (score 0):

This code needs a lot of improvement but start with this simple thing:

```
 if (eventName!=null)  eventName(Id);
```

don't know where id is coming from though, but the check is there to prevent the nullreference exception in case nobody registered for the event.

So if this code did not run :

```
g.eventName += new userControlPage.abcDel(MyParentMethod);
```

and you do Callhere,

then you have a problem, because nobody has registered yet.

Comment: Yes the eventName is null. Id is coming from a different logic. Could you help me in this ?

Comment: I already did, the eventName is null because nobody registered for the event. Who is calling Callhere ? This code : g.eventName += new userControlPage.abcDel(MyParentMethod); needs to execute before your call to Callhere.

Comment: I dont want want null, I want to pass data from user control to the main page. I read the article here : http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/03/calling-method-of-parent-page-from-user.html. Trying to do the same

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/ is what you need. That article is crappy and does not look to be finished, it does not explain anything.